# why maven fail to collect another internal dependency project?

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml

my whole pom construct follow as:

```
simple-parent2-|
               |-pom.xml
               |-simple-model2-|
                                pom.xml
               |-simple-weather2-|
                                pom.xml
```

simple-weather2 is depend on simple-model2

so ,the simple-parent2 pom.xml follow as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>kursk.practice.ch07</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-parent2</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>simple-parent2</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <modules>
     <module>simple-model2</module>
     <module>simple-weather2</module>
     <!--
     <module>simple-persist2</module>
     <module>simple-webapp2</module>
     <module>simple-command2</module>
     -->
  </modules>

  <build>
     <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                 <source>1.5</source>
                 <target>1.5</target>
              </configuration>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

the simple-model2 pom.xml follow as :

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
      <groupId>kursk.practice.ch07</groupId>
      <artifactId>simple-parent2</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>kursk.practice.ch07</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-model2</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>simple-model2</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </project>
```

the simple-weather2 pom.xml follow as, the simple-model2 is one of dependencies.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>kursk.practice.ch07</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent2</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>kursk.practice.ch07</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-weather2</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <name>simple-weather2</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>kursk.practice.ch07</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-model2</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

first, I install simple-model2 ,it's success!

```
kursk@KURSK-PC /D/CodeSpace/maven/simple-parent2/simple-model2
$ mvn install
.....
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.445s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 08 16:22:16 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

second, I exec denpendency:tree on simple-weather2 folder,but maven report fail to collect simple-model2 and simple-parent2!

```
kursk@KURSK-PC /D/CodeSpace/maven/simple-parent2/simple-weather2
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building simple-weather2 1.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.411s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 08 16:27:19 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project simple-weather2: Could not resolve dependencies for project kursk.practice.ch07:simple-weather2:jar:1.1: Failed to collect de
pendencies at kursk.practice.ch07:simple-model2:jar:1.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for kursk.practice.ch07:simple-model2:jar:1.1: Failure to find kursk.practi
ce.ch07:simple-parent2:pom:1.1 in http://dev.joget.org/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the up
date interval of joget-internal has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

but I can find them in my repository in local repository

```
kursk@KURSK-PC /C/Users/kursk/.m2/repository/kursk/practice/ch07
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 kursk    Administ        0 Mar  8 15:06 simple-model2
drwxr-xr-x    3 kursk    Administ        0 Mar  8 15:07 simple-parent2
```

what's wrong in my steps?why maven can't find internal dependency project?

Comment: try to run mvn again with `-U` parameter

Comment: no effect,I have tried

Answer (score 1):

sorry,it's my fault,I didn't read carafully. now, I see.

I didn't exec "mvn clean install" from simple-parent2 project, so simple-parent2 and simple-model2 jar file didn't locate in local cache.

after exec "mvn clean install" from simple-parent2 project ,exec "mvn dependency:tree" from simple-weather2 project is work!

so,follow text is extracted from 《maven-definitive-guide》

> When Maven is executed against a project with submodules, Maven first loads the
>   parent POM and locates all of the submodule POMs. Maven then puts all of these
>   project POMs into something called the Maven Reactor which analyzes the
>   dependencies between modules. The Reactor takes care of ordering components to
>   ensure that interdependent modules are compiled and installed in the proper order.
>
> Note:
>   The Reactor preserves the order of modules as defined in the POM unless
>   changes need to be made. A helpful mental model for this is to picture
>   that modules with dependencies on sibling projects are "pushed down"
>   the list until the dependency ordering is satisfied. On rare occasions, it
>   may be handy to rearrange the module order of your build -- for example
>   if you want a frequently unstable module towards the beginning of the
>   build.
>   100